# How to get extended event details in fullcalendar

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler, fullcalendar-5

I have a situation where my event extends from the 15 to 30 min and when i clicked on 2nd slot to add another event then how can i get the slots details ? like there is already an event for this slot.
I want to get selected slot details when i clicked on the hi-lighted spot.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can select the slot using the `select` callback functionality, just like any other slot - the fact it's covered by an event doesn't really matter.

Basic example:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById("calendar");

  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    headerToolbar: {
      right: "dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay",
      center: "title",
      left: "prevYear,prev,next,nextYear"
    },
    initialView: "timeGridDay",
    initialDate: "2021-04-01",
    selectable: true, //ENABLE SELECTIONS
    select: function (args) { //HANDLE THE SELECTION EVENT
      console.log(args); //REPLACE THIS WITH WHATEVER YOU WANT TO DO WHEN SELECTION HAPPENS
    },
    events: [
      {
        title: "Sales Meeting",
        start: new Date(2021, 03, 1, 10, 30),
        end: new Date(2021, 03, 1, 11, 30),
        allDay: false
      }
    ]
  });

  calendar.render();
});
```

Live demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/XWpQYpQ

Documentation: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/date-clicking-selecting

Comment: Thank you for your response.
but my situation is bit different, i have to stop user to create another event if one is already there and i do not have info for already existed event in select callback.

Comment: Ah I see. That wasn't clear in your question. You need [selectOverlap](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/selectOverlap) for that. Please review the documentation.